# Can not install postgres-passport

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, passport-local

I am trying to install passport-local-postgres package for my node server but it keeps failing on bcrypt.
npm install passport-local-postgres --save
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@1.0.3: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes 
But I have installed bcrypt 3.0 but It does not see the bcrypt 3.0 and tries to download bcrypt 1.0.3 and bcrypt 1.0.3 just fails on install script
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

I already tried install version 2.x of bscrypt but that does not work either